# AlwaysEncrypted Column Using CNG key - encrypted column encryption key may be corrupt

Tags: sql-server, powershell, encryption, cryptography, sql-server-2016

Setup: I'm trying to read data from an encrypted column

- Always Encrypted column was setup on Server A for the local sql instance that it's hosting(I know it defeats the purpose for AE, but this is just for testing)
- Now I am trying to decrypt the data from Server B by first Exporting the CNG key from server A and importing it in server B and recreating an CNG key with the same configurations and name but I am receiving this error when I try to read data from Server B:

  ```
  Msg 0, Level 11, State 0, Line 0
  Failed to decrypt column 'Name'.
  Msg 0, Level 11, State 0, Line 0
  Failed to decrypt a column encryption key using key store provider: 'MSSQL_CNG_STORE'. Verify the properties of the column encryption key and its column master key in your database. The last 10 bytes of the encrypted column encryption key are: 'U3-2A-2V-2D-F5-03-C7-C9-4A-C4'.
  Msg 0, Level 11, State 0, Line 0
  The specified encrypted column encryption key signature does not match the signature computed with the column master key (asymmetric key) in 'Microsoft Software Key Storage Provider/AE_CNG_PS_test'. The encrypted column encryption key may be corrupt, or the specified path may be incorrect.
  Parameter name: encryptedColumnEncryptionKey
  ```

---

Code is below:

**@Server A**

- CNG Key Creation for Creating Master Key and Encryption Key

  ```
  # Create a column master key in a key store that has a CNG provider, a.k.a key store provider (KSP).
  $cngProviderName = "Microsoft Software Key Storage Provider" # If you have an HSM, you can use a KSP for your HSM instead of a Microsoft KSP
  $cngAlgorithmName = "RSA"
  $cngKeySize = 2048 # Recommended key size for Always Encrypted column master keys
  $cngKeyName = "AE_CNG_PS_test" # Name identifying your new key in the KSP
  $cngProvider = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.CngProvider($cngProviderName)
  $cngKeyParams = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.CngKeyCreationParameters
  $cngKeyParams.provider = $cngProvider
  $cngKeyParams.KeyCreationOptions = [System.Security.Cryptography.CngKeyCreationOptions]::OverwriteExistingKey
  $keySizeProperty = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.CngProperty("Length", [System.BitConverter]::GetBytes($cngKeySize), [System.Security.Cryptography.CngPropertyOptions]::None);
  $cngKeyParams.Parameters.Add($keySizeProperty)
  $cngAlgorithm = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.CngAlgorithm($cngAlgorithmName)
  $cngKey = [System.Security.Cryptography.CngKey]::Create($cngAlgorithm, $cngKeyName, $cngKeyParams)
  ```
- Exporting the CNG key

  ```
  [byte]$PubKey = $cngKey.Export([System.Security.Cryptography.CngKeyBlobFormat]::GenericPublicBlob)
  [String]$ExpPubKey = [Convert]::ToBase64String($PubKey)
  $ExpPubKey | Out-File C:\FakePath\PubKey.txt
  ## C:\FakePath\PubKey.txt = UlNasasdasgerferferferfsASIurh34e23t23gSgzxkTFTuFpPYlTzYAYuurypos6nutcXg5Ek4wXQ/JsDLAXXcKxTYl/SBo490b1QP303rwXsdgU67Hy67aXrhywCO9BjzXAEf0qJDLqt3r7RAUByrSaUg1Jp2RrdTb7uS6Vf8bDYmwDDSfqQbEHkm2fA36diLGDxQ==
  ```
- CNG Key For Server A

  ```
  PS C:\Users\Test> $cngKey
  AlgorithmGroup     : RSA
  Algorithm          : RSA
  ExportPolicy       : None
  Handle             : Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeNCryptKeyHandle
  IsEphemeral        : False
  IsMachineKey       : False
  KeyName            : AE_CNG_PS_test
  KeySize            : 2048
  KeyUsage           : AllUsages
  ParentWindowHandle : 0
  Provider           : Microsoft Software Key Storage Provider
  ProviderHandle     : Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeNCryptProviderHandle
  UniqueName         : va9356ed810cc3dg272b6a921g53daad_b13750ab-b64d-4234-aff4-1ffs23593b6fca
  UIPolicy           : System.Security.Cryptography.CngUIPolicy
  ```

**@Server B**

- Import the CNG Key

  ```
  [string]$ImpPubKey = 'UlNasasdasgerferferferfsASIurh34e23t23gSgzxkTFTuFpPYlTzYAYuurypos6nutcXg5Ek4wXQ/JsDLAXXcKxTYl/SBo490b1QP303rwXsdgU67Hy67aXrhywCO9BjzXAEf0qJDLqt3r7RAUByrSaUg1Jp2RrdTb7uS6Vf8bDYmwDDSfqQbEHkm2fA36diLGDxQ=='
  $ImpBlob = [Convert]::FromBase64String($ImpPubKey)
  $cngKey = [System.Security.Cryptography.CngKey]::Import($ImpBlob,[System.Security.Cryptography.CngKeyBlobFormat]::GenericPublicBlob)
  $cngKeyParams = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.CngKeyCreationParameters
  $cngKeyParams.provider = $cngKey.Provider
  $cngKeyParams.KeyCreationOptions = [System.Security.Cryptography.CngKeyCreationOptions]::OverwriteExistingKey
  $keySizeProperty = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.CngProperty("Length", [System.BitConverter]::GetBytes($cngKey.KeySize), [System.Security.Cryptography.CngPropertyOptions]::None);
  $cngKeyParams.Parameters.Add($keySizeProperty)

  $NewlyCreatedCNGFromImport = [System.Security.Cryptography.CngKey]::Create($cngKey.Algorithm,'AE_CNG_PS_test',$cngKeyParams)
  ```
- CNG for newly created CNG in Server B

  ```
  PS C:\Users\Test> $NewlyCreatedCNGFromImport

  AlgorithmGroup     : RSA
  Algorithm          : RSA
  ExportPolicy       : None
  Handle             : Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeNCryptKeyHandle
  IsEphemeral        : False
  IsMachineKey       : False
  KeyName            : AE_CNG_PS_test
  KeySize            : 2048
  KeyUsage           : AllUsages
  ParentWindowHandle : 0
  Provider           : Microsoft Software Key Storage Provider
  ProviderHandle     : Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeNCryptProviderHandle
  UniqueName         : a25ag6356ed810c3fd472shees121ea4daad_f023yd98-44V3-75G7-819b-02cf6d3t5470
  UIPolicy           : System.Security.Cryptography.CngUIPolicy
  ```

It seems that when I read the data of Sever A from Server B, SQL cannot find or decrypt the column using the CNG key which was imported. Could it be an issue for the path? or an issue on the export/import(+recreate in server B) of the CNG key?

Comment: hey man, I was wondering if you have an idea regarding this @gotqn

Comment: Just to be sure, you seem to be wanting to export a *public key* and then try to decrypt with it?

Comment: Yes @MaartenBodewes. Actually it is part of the Always Encrypted Column of SQL 2016. Basically the problem is that I am unable to decrypt it using the imported CNG key from ServerA.

Comment: You need a private key to decrypt. Public keys are used for verification and / or encryption, not signature generation or decryption - you need a private key for that.

Comment: So i need to recreate the key and encryption process using a private key right and then export that private key and recreate that key in Server B and decrypt the data there?@MaartenBodewes

Comment: That would be one way to do things, yes. For decryption you need the private key, and distributing it over multiple machines is one way to get access to the functions performed using the key.